# why is the entire object is following one face when i scale or move it?

Tags: objects, faces, scale

hi im new to blender and i would like to know how to move the face im selecting and not have the entire object follow[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WWh4.png)

[image]

Comment: Well, based on the shape of your inset, your object has non uniform scale. Select it in Object mode then press Ctrl+A and select "Scale". This might not be the problem, however, but needs fixing nonetheless. Its hard to tell, but in your image it looks like there may be faces selected on other sides as well. If  that's not the case (and just a trick of the image), my last guess is that you have proportional editing on - press O to turn it off.

Comment: thanks, proportional editing was ON so that solved it